How to track even dynamic memory allocation for a certain class?
I understand I can provide a custom allocator for most of the standard containers. If I record memory allocations in this custom allocator, then I can keep track of memory allocations. For example, with the help of MyAllocator in std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T>>, we can always tell how much memory is consumed by this vector.
However, such allocators only apply to standard containers. If we want to keep track of a custom class, we have to come up with some other ideas.
One idea is that we can override operator new and operator new []. However, there are some drawbacks:

operator new and operator new [] apply only to allocations by the new operators, which usually allocates on the heap. OK, maybe this is not too much of a problem since we care about heap memory the most.

operator new and operator new [] do not apply to dynamic memory allocations inside the class. For example, given type T, if I allocated some memory by a = new R [10000] in T::T(), then such memory allocation will not be tracked by operator new and operator new [] for T.

Talk more about the upper case. There is a problem even if I have also implemented R's operator new. Because it only allows me to summarize how much memory T allocates, and how much memory R allocates, respectively. However what I want to know is how much memory T allocates including all its fields at some point in time. That means if I called a = new R [10000], then I can somehow find the instance of T has allocated sizeof(T) + sizeof(R) * 1000, rather than that the instance of T has allocated sizeof(T) and another 1000 instances of R have allocated sizeof(R).


So, I wonder how to do this.

Why do you want to do that?

@Yksisarvinen I want to track memory usage online. I know I can use jemalloc to dump a snapshot of heap profiling. However, if you want to see how the memory allocation of a certain component goes up and down in a grafana panel, then heap profiling is not enough.

Are you able to modify the "custom class" (in particular all its constructors, destructor, and any other functions that allocate memory) or are you trying to do tracking without help of the class itself?

@Peter Yes, I can modify a several classes. However, I can't modify all related classes. For example, given X {A a; std::vector<B> vb; std::map<B, std::list<C>>}, or even more complex object, by only modifying the class of A, I can get all memory allocated automatically or dynamicly by class A. Other changes or even "hack"s could also be take into consideration. What I want to avoid is to introduce some interface, and make all related class to adapt it.
